# Report with dynamic number of columns

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to have a report with an arbitrary number of columns in MS Access?
The user may add or remove the items that are shown in the column (not from within the report itself). In the cells of the report I need to put a checkbox; the click event of the checkbox will be managed by a macro.

The result should looks like the image here:

[image: Grid with Rows and Columns]

The user will have a form for adding new superheroes, and a different form for adding weapons and powers. Then I want him to be able to view a summary of all the superheroes and their powers.
Also, the user shall be able to assign or remove a weapon by clicking on the checkbox, but this will be handled with a macro activated by the click event on the checkbox.
(Of course the real case is not about superheroes!)

**Additional comments**

At the moments weapons are fields, and names are records.
The DB structure will be modified so that weapons will be records, as well as names.
Weapons are assigned to groups, and each user belong to a certain group.

So, the Users table is something like:

```
ID    Name    Group
1     James   1
2     Austin  1
3     Indy    2
```

The Groups table looks like:

```
GroupID  GroupName
1        Spy
2        Archeologist
```

The Weapons table looks like:

```
WeaponID  GroupID  [WeaponName]
1         1        [Gun]
2         1        [Charm]
3         2        [Whip]
...
```

I can have the final result like this:

```
UserID    WeaponID   UserHasWeapon
1         1          True
1         2          True
1         3          False
2         1          True
...
```

or like this:

[image: Crosstab query]

Comment: Not without lots of VBA or some other programming tool. Question is too broad. But why would the columns be dynamic? The output you show might be result of a CROSSTAB query. But hard to say without knowing data structure.

Comment: Yes, the output will be the result of a crosstab query. Long story short, the company at first decided that they would only buy certain weapons, and a selection of weapons would have been distributed to superheroes depending on where they lived. Then they decided they could buy also other weapons as they found bargains on Amazon. So I need to transform fields into records, but this is not the problem. The problem is that they want to keep the same mask for assigning weapons to superheros. Of course I can also tell them the inputing method must be changed, though I'd try to keep it the same.

Comment: Correction to my comment. A subreport can have a query object as SourceObject. This way no textbox controls are needed. Columns are dynamic. No VBA. However, always a risk that query width will exceed report design width.

Comment: I’m going to have a look at subreports. Never used them before exactly because I don’t like the fact that adapting the size to the content is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have those tables:

[image: Tables]

Add the following queries:

**SalesDetails**

```
SELECT Sales.SaleId, Sales.CustomerId, Customers.CustomerName,
    Sales.WeaponId, Weapons.WeaponName
FROM Weapons INNER JOIN
(
    Customers INNER JOIN Sales
    ON Customers.CustomerId = Sales.CustomerId
) ON Weapons.WeaponId = Sales.WeaponId
GROUP BY Sales.SaleId, Sales.CustomerId, Customers.CustomerName,
    Sales.WeaponId, Weapons.WeaponName;
```

**Sum**

```
SELECT SalesDetails.CustomerName, SalesDetails.WeaponName,
    Count(SalesDetails.WeaponId) AS CountOfWeaponId
FROM SalesDetails
GROUP BY SalesDetails.CustomerName, SalesDetails.WeaponName;
```

**Note:** If you want the weapons as columns, use a `Crosstab` query.